# Create Fossil repository from existing project files

Tags: dvcs, fossil

I'd expect this to be explained in the beginner's quick start guide, because almost everyone who starts with fossil will have projects that he wants to start managing with fossil. Yet I could not find an explanation anywhere in the documentation.

(I'm coming from git, which was way too heavy for my needs, but at least creating a new repository in an existing folder was easy ...)

(tried to answer my question but have insufficient reputation. so here it is:)

I think I figured it out myself. Here's what I did, for beginners:

1. Create directory for repositories, `C:\www\fossil`
2. Enter `fossil` directory
3. `fossil init projectname`
4. Enter directory of existing project `C:\www\projectname`
5. `fossil open ../fossil/projectname`
6. `fossil add *.*`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some comments:

- Step 3. can be alternatively done with `fossil new` instead of `fossil init`.
- Step 6 should be `fossil add .`; this is recursive. fossil does not abide by the old, Microsoft rule that states `*.*` means every single file even without extension. `fossil add *.*` will merely add all files and directories that contain a dot in their name.
- Step 7 should be `fossil commit -m "Initial contents of my project"`

Comment: Thanks! Fossil may be simple compared to git, but still, it should not claim to be simple. It is not. I spent most of the day with it, if it was simple, I'd know EVERYTHING about it by now ...

Comment: @Ral: Actually, I find that fossil is simple, but you have to unlearn git concepts if you want to switch to it. The main thing is that fossil needs you to create a database (aka repository) and associate your working directories with it (open command). Once you've understood that, you master the main concept behind fossil.